# Convert NSString to NSDate results in NULL

Tags: objective-c

I want to convert the following date: 2010-02-01T13:58:58.513Z

Which is stored in a `NSString`to and `NSDate`.

The following however just shows "NULL" in the debugger

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

[formatter setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.tttZ"];

NSLog(@"Output: %@", [formatter dateFromString:@"2010-02-01T13:58:58.513Z"]);

[formatter release];
```

Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to escape the "T" in the format string with single quotes.

```
[formatter setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-DD'T'HH:MM:SS.tttZ"];
```

--

**Edit:** your formatters aren't completely correct either. ttt for instance is not a valid formatter according to the documentation. [Official documentation](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Date_Format_Patterns)

If I do this I can get it to work, but that doesn't solve the Z problem:

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-DD'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS"];
NSLog(@"Output: %@", [formatter dateFromString:@"2010-02-01T13:58:58.513"]);
[formatter release];
```

--

**Edit 2:** Bingo, found the correct formatter.

```
[formatter setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"];
```

Comment: How about the Z ? It's still null with that.

Comment: Working on it, one moment, the Z is not the only problem.

Comment: Well that displays something else than null. But it gives me the wrong date: 2010-01-01.

Comment: DD is for day of year, should be dd. Fixed it in the answer.

Comment: Be careful that your Z timezone is not interpreted

Answer (score 0):

Best Guess: Your date format has a space in it.  Try this:

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

[formatter setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-DD'T'HH:mm:SS.SSS'Z'"];

NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:@"2010-02-01T13:58:58.513Z"];

NSLog(@"Output: %@", [date description]);

[formatter release];
```

Comment: Sorry.  Try my fix, it prints for me.

Comment: It does print something, but the wrong date. Prints 2010-01-01

Answer (score 0):

There are several problem in your format :

- MM is for month while mm is for minutes
- SS does not exists, use ss instead
- same for ttt, use AAA
- there is space between in your format string that looks like a typo but will cause failure

what time zone does Z code stand for at the end of your time (2010-02-01T13:58:58.513Z)

try

```
[formatter setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.AAA'Z'"];
```

This will create a GMT Time because it recognize the Z ate the end a as simple letter and not as time zone.

**Edit** : `[formatter setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"]`

Comment: Still gives me: "Output: (null)".

Comment: AAA is for milliseconds in day, while SSS is for fractional seconds, which I think is what he means.